# How can I write an iterative function that bases the current row output off of the prior row output?

Tags: postgresql

I need to determine whether my current row value is positive or negative, which is a function of a starting value, scheduled increases, and daily decrement (which is different depending on if the prior day output value was positive or negative).

I only know my starting number for day 1, my schedule of increases, and my decrement values if positive or negative.

If "Prior Day Output" + "Today scheduled increase" is positive, then "Prior Day Output" + "Today scheduled increase" - 2(decrement value)
If "Prior Day Output" + "Today scheduled increase" is negative, then "Prior Day Output" + "Today scheduled increase" - 1(decrement value)

I haven't tried anything, as I can't think of an algebraic way to perform this. New to iterative functions or loops.

Here is the data I have to start with:

[image]

Here is what I want to end with:

[image]

Comment: Window functions might help for what you are looking for.  A bit hard to say - would help if you can add samples of the data and what you are looking to achieve.

Comment: Can you provide a data set that shows what you are expecting?

Comment: Thanks - sorry I couldn't figure our how to paste images before. Hopefully this helps explain what I'm trying to do.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe I have a solution for you.

**Note:** You have a stipulation saying if `start_val` is positive (`>= 0`) set the decrement to `2` but, on `Day 11` of your output example you have the decrement set to `1` where `start_val + increase = 0`.

This solution will match your example output which considers `0` to be negative. That is easily changeable in the segment that sets `new_dec`. Just move the `=` to the appropriate location.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION update_vals()
RETURNS SETOF test
AS
$$
DECLARE
    new_dec     integer;
    new_end     integer;
    new_start   integer;
    rec         record;
BEGIN
    FOR rec IN
        SELECT * FROM test
    LOOP
        new_start := NULL::integer;

        IF rec.start_val IS NULL
        THEN
            SELECT end_val
            INTO new_start
            FROM
            (
                SELECT MAX(id) last_id FROM test WHERE id < rec.id
            ) a
            JOIN test ON id = a.last_id
            ;
        END IF;

        IF COALESCE(rec.start_val, new_start) + rec.increase > 0
        THEN
            new_dec := 2;
        ELSIF COALESCE(rec.start_val, new_start) + rec.increase <= 0
        THEN
            new_dec := 1;
        END IF;

        new_end := COALESCE(rec.start_val, new_start) + rec.increase - new_dec;

        IF new_start IS NOT NULL
        THEN
            RETURN QUERY
            UPDATE test
            SET (start_val, decrement, end_val) = (new_start, new_dec, new_end)
            WHERE id = rec.id
            RETURNING *
            ;
        ELSE
            RETURN QUERY
            UPDATE test
            SET (decrement, end_val) = (new_dec, new_end)
            WHERE id = rec.id
            RETURNING *
            ;
        END IF;
    END LOOP;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE PLPGSQL;
```

[Here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/j8kx28k7snqjMd3wr9FxGw/3) is a db-fiddle to show a working example.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I had a guy who said he could do this with Python with no issue. Scalability was an issue and it would have taken over 16 hours to run through all our data using that method. I'm just getting into using this solution and it has worked very will in the first testing for small datasets! Testing it with larger datasets (1m+ rows) and seeing how scalable and quick it runs. I'll follow up again after.

Comment: PS - the db-fiddle was a HUGE help to me in understanding the code you provided, thank you!

Comment: You're welcome. This does seem like something the pandas library could do pretty well in python. Maybe better than postgres itself so I'd be curious in the results for this solution.